# Understanding the proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality Using the AM-GM Inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The AM - GM Inequality states that the arithmetic mean of a set of numbers $a_1,a_2...a_n$, will always be greater than or equal to the geometric mean of the same set.

More formally,

$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n{a_i}}$

This has many applications, 1 of them specifically being to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, which states that for a set $a_1,a_2...a_n$, and a set $b_1,b_2...b_n$, that the sum of the squares of each set multiplied together is greater than or equal to the square of the dot product of the two sets.

$\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i^2} \space \times \space \sum_{i=1}^n{b_i^2} \space\space\geq\space\sum_{i=1}^n{a_ib_i}$

Within my textbook, there is a proof for the CS inequality that applies the AM-GM inequality, and I am not completely sure what was done to achieve their result.

Below is the proof.

> Let $A =\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i^2}} \space$ and $B =\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{b_i^2}} \space$
>
> Applying the AM-GM inequality, we have
> $\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{a_ib_i}{AB}} \leq \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{a_i^2}{A^2}+\frac{b_i^2}{B^2})} = 1$
> By cross multiplying...

The proof then continues into basic algebra to prove the inequality. My question, is where that crazy sigma equation came from.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, be more careful choosing the tags. This is not a question of Measure Theory.

Comment: I apologize. I saw the word sigma when I searched Algebra and clicked.

Comment: The LHS should be $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i b_i}{AB}$. Is that what is confusing you?

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you, but unfortunately no. I fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean in this case is between two terms:
$a_i^2/A^2$ and $b_i^2/B^2$. If you write the AM-GM inequality for these terms for any given $i\in\{1,2,3...,n\}$, you get
$\sqrt{ a_i^2/A^2 \times b_i^2/B^2 }\leq \frac{1}{2}(a_i^2/A^2 + b_i^2/B^2) $.

Summing both sides of this inequality across all $i$ preserves the inequality, and the resulting right hand side simplifies to one, giving the desired crazy sigma equation.

Comment: So are you saying that the terms are $\frac{a_1^2}{A^2}, \frac{a_2^2}{A^2}...\frac{a_n^2}{A^2}$. Also including the $b$ counterparts?

Comment: For any particular $i\in \{1,2,3,...\}$, there are only two relevant terms involved in computing the means: $a^2_i/A^2$  and $b^2_i/B^2$.  Write the AM-GM inequality for the mean of these  two terms.  Summing both sides of this inequality across all $i$ preserves the inequality.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh!!!!! I just realized that when I tried it out. It is multiple AMGM inequalities summed together.

Comment: Essentially, yes-added more detail to my explanation

Comment: Thank you so much!